# C++ Calculate the sum and product of all integer numbers error

Tags: c++, sum, product

Write a program to prompt user for two integer numbers lower and upper.
then Calculate the sum and product of all integer numbers between lower and upper  that are multiples of 3
using a for loop, +=, *=
I tried creating a code for this but it keeps on looping without giving me total_sum any tips to how i can fix it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int lower_num{}, upper_num{}, sum_lower, sum_upper, total_sum;
int i = 1;
for (int i = lower_num; i <= upper_num; i++) {
if (i % 3 == 0) {
cout << "enter lower number:";
cin >> lower_num;
cout << " enter upper number:";
cin >> upper_num;
sum_lower = 3 * lower_num;
sum_upper = 3 * upper_num;
total_sum = sum_lower + sum_upper;
}
else
exit;
}
cout << "sum of multiple of 3 between " << lower_num << "and " << upper_num << "="
<< total_sum;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Is there a specific problem you're having with your attempt to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Nice homework question (next time make it less obvious).

To do it just use a for loop with an increment of 3, and a range from your minimum to your maximum (to do multiples of 3) and just add the current value of the loop onto a counter variable that starts at 0 (for the multiplication make the counter start at 1 and multiply it by the current loop value).

Comment: thank you for the explanation and this is not a homework i am practicing for my exam and i was stuck on this question since the code i created had an error

Comment: "had an error" is not specific enough for Stack Overflow. Please specify your issues in more detail so you can be helped.

Comment: can I post my code here and can you take a look. cause i can't find my error

Comment: @meme yes, you are meant to post your code here. Otherwise it is harder to help you

Comment: i just added the code i created it keeps on looping and i can't get the answer for the total_sum but i don't know where is the error exactly